# Get a Windows file information using C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, boost

Is there any way to can check for some properties of a Windows file using C++?
The wanted formation is such as last access date, MIME Type, ...

For some other information extraction I am using Boost Filesystem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no reliable way to get either of them. The MIME type is meta-information. It is not a property of a file as such; it is set either by the producer or the OS (or both or neither). The last access date can be disabled on Windows. Again, the information you get back is unreliable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the file modification date, you could use Windows' API directly ([`GetFileTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx)) or use [`boost::filesystem::last_write_time()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#last_write_time).

As for MIME type, there's no real API as far as I'm aware. You'll essentially have to read the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.<yourextension>` and look for a value `Content Type`. If there is one, it includes the MIME type that is set for the extension.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes I already knew how to get the last modification date from boost. I will try that of the MIME

Answer (score 4):

The aims of C++ and boost are to be cross-platform. The language, the standard library and the boost library try to abstract the idiosyncrasies of the various environments from you, so your stated goal is inherently contentious with writing **standard** C++.

However if you know that you'll be compiling and running specifically on Windows you can wrap your code inside

```
#ifdef _WIN32
/* code here */
#endif
```

and call `BOOL WINAPI GetFileAttributesEx(...)` directly.

`GetFileAttributesEx` is part of kernel32.dll, which is loaded into every process, so you should be able to compile and link against it if you've included `<windows.h>` in your translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

To get last access time, you can always use `stat()`, which is available on any OS (and it does not need Boost either).

As for MIME type, I don't think there is simple way to get that without analyzing file content.

Comment: MIME type is not about analyzing file contents, it's either set/passed somewhere (e.g. in a HTTP header) or determined by the file extension. You shouldn't look into the file to determine the contents, because this can lead to further problems (e.g. circumventing intentional restrictions; like no video files playback or similar)